# Trying to add /proc/kallsyms into gdb for vmlinux debugging :`/proc/kallsyms': can't read symbols: File format not recognized

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, kernel

I am trying to debug running kernel by extracting vmlinux using extract-vmlinux, here is my list of steps

1. extracted the vmlinux from vmlinuz using ~/script/extract-vmlinux

```
./extract-vmlinux bzImage > vmlinux
objdump -DS vmlinux |less
Disassembly of section .text:

ffffffff80200000 <.text>:
ffffffff80200000:       48 8d 25 f1 3f 40 01    lea    0x1403ff1(%rip),%rsp        # 0xffffffff81603ff8
ffffffff80200007:       e8 9d 01 00 00          callq  0xffffffff802001a9
ffffffff8020000c:       48 8d 2d ed ff ff ff    lea    -0x13(%rip),%rbp        # 0xffffffff80200000
ffffffff80200013:       48 81 ed 00 00 20 00    sub    $0x200000,%rbp
ffffffff8020001a:       f7 c5 ff ff 1f 00       test   $0x1fffff,%ebp
ffffffff80200020:       0f 85 8f 02 00 00       jne    0xffffffff802002b5
ffffffff80200026:       48 8d 05 d3 ff ff ff    lea    -0x2d(%rip),%rax        # 0xffffffff80200000
ffffffff8020002d:       48 c1 e8 2e             shr    $0x2e,%rax
ffffffff80200031:       0f 85 7e 02 00 00       jne    0xffffffff802002b5
ffffffff80200037:       48 01 2d ba ef 60 01    add    %rbp,0x160efba(%rip)        # 0xffffffff8180eff8
ffffffff8020003e:       48 01 2d ab bf 40 01    add    %rbp,0x140bfab(%rip)        # 0xffffffff8160bff0
ffffffff80200045:       48 01 2d ac bf 40 01    add    %rbp,0x140bfac(%rip)        # 0xffffffff8160bff8
ffffffff8020004c:       48 01 2d 7d df 40 01    add    %rbp,0x140df7d(%rip)        # 0xffffffff8160dfd0
ffffffff80200053:       48 8d 3d a6 ff ff ff    lea    -0x5a(%rip),%rdi        # 0xffffffff80200000
ffffffff8020005a:       48 8d 1d 9f df 60 01    lea    0x160df9f(%rip),%rbx        # 0xffffffff8180e000
ffffffff80200061:       48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
ffffffff80200064:       48 c1 e8 27             shr    $0x27,%rax
ffffffff80200068:       48 8d 93 63 10 00 00    lea    0x1063(%rbx),%rdx
ffffffff8020006f:       48 89 14 c3             mov    %rdx,(%rbx,%rax,8)
ffffffff80200073:       48 89 54 c3 08          mov    %rdx,0x8(%rbx,%rax,8)


2) Used this vmlinux to load into gdb and use /proc/kcore has core file
 gdb ./vmlinux /proc/kcore
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-poky-linux".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./vmlinux...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New process 1]
Core was generated by `BOOT_IMAGE=/junos-evo-install-acx-x86-64-20.4I20200915151620-EVO_raghuh/bzImage'.
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
(gdb) add-symbol-file /proc/kallsyms 0xffffffff80200000
add symbol table from file "/proc/kallsyms" at
        .text_addr = 0xffffffff80200000
(y or n) y
`/proc/kallsyms': can't read symbols: File format not recognized.
(gdb)
```

I have tried it on multiple systems and I am getting this `/proc/kallsyms': can't read symbols: File format not recognized. error

Whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

> `'/proc/kallsyms': can't read symbols: File format not recognized.`

The `/proc/kallsyms` is a *text* file describing where all the code was loaded.

*Of course* GDB can't add symbols from it -- it's not an `ELF` file.

It looks like your kernel jumped to `NULL` pointer. You may get some clues about how it got there from the output of `where` command.